# SynchronizationAttribute in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I recently migrated a .NET Framework 4.0 app to .NET Core and I'm 99% there except for a multithreading issue. It seems that .NET Core isn't supporting the `[Synchronization]` attribute anymore or am I overlooking something.

I have a class that I've used for threading in the past that worked fine.
Now I'm seeing the squiggly lines indicating that I may be missing a reference?

I'm using .NET 6.

```
[Synchronization]
public class threaded
{...}
```

Comment: In case you asking about `System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.SynchronizationAttribute`, the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.synchronizationattribute?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to) only lists .NET Framework, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac in the *Applies to* section.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `SynchronizationAttribute` types, both are only available in .NET Framework.

- [.NET Framework technologies unavailable on .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable) and .NET 5+, see [Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable#remoting).

  > .NET Remoting isn't supported on .NET 5+ (and .NET Core). .NET remoting was identified as a problematic architecture. It's used for communicating across application domains, which are no longer supported. Also, remoting requires runtime support, which is expensive to maintain.
- [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/), see [Unavailable technologies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/#unavailable-technologies).

  > Remoting is used for communicating across application domains, which are no longer supported.
- `System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.SynchronizationAttribute` documentation, see [Applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.synchronizationattribute?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to).
- `System.EnterpriseServices.SynchronizationAttribute` documentation, see [Applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enterpriseservices.synchronizationattribute?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to).
- [Synchronizing data for multithreading.](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/standard/threading/synchronizing-data-for-multithreading.md)

  > Synchronized contexts. For .NET Framework and Xamarin applications only, you can use the `xref:System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.SynchronizationAttribute` to enable simple, automatic synchronization for `xref:System.ContextBoundObject` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Deprecated Function.